# Ionic PDFJS Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'lib/ui/index.html'

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, pdf.js, pdftron

I am trying to open a pdf in my ionic 5 application with the plugin
npm i @ pdftron / pdfjs-express --save
but ionic shows me the error Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'lib / ui / index.html'
please how to correct this error?
my code:

app.component.html

```
<div class="page">
      <div class="header">Angular sample</div>
       <div #viewer class="viewer"></div>
  </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
 import WebViewer from '@pdftron/pdfjs-express';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild('viewer', { static: false }) viewer: ElementRef;
  wvInstance: any;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

  WebViewer({
  path: '../lib',
  initialDoc: '../files/webviewer-demo-annotated.pdf'
}, this.viewer.nativeElement).then(instance => {
  this.wvInstance = instance;
})
}

ngOnInit() {

}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you used any of our angular samples here https://github.com/PDFTron?q=angular? You can clone one of the samples and take a look at how it is implemented

Comment: by cloning your project on github, everything works fine.
I had the error when trying to implement this in an ionic 5 project.
finally I solved the problem by moving the lib folder of PDFTron in the assets folder of ionic

Comment: That sounds great you were able to find the issue. Let us know if anything else happens!

Comment: Is it possible to store a file in the internal memory of the phone and display it with PDFTron?